# Who's the guy who triggered the alarm?

Tags: character, boondock-saints

In the final courtroom scene, the guy in the screenshot below sneaks over and triggers a fire alarm in the courthouse. Who is he?

[image]

Comment: I tried to attack this from the backside, but was unsuccessful. I've seen the actor before, but cannot place him on IMDB within the complete cast listing.

Comment: What I turn up is that it's listed as being Detective "Dolly" Alapopskalius played actor David Ferry. However, it's hard to find pictures of him that look like this screenshot. I can't be certain. But according to the internets that's who it is.

Comment: @BenPlont That seems plausible and he does [look](http://theboondocksaints.wikia.com/wiki/Detective_Dolly) a little like him, I suppose. The Wikia link also states that he helped the Saints kill Papa Joe. Please convert your comment into an answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer to this question is: Detective "Dolly" Alapopskalius.

He is the character that I found to be credited with pulling the fire-alarm in the script to the sequel (of Boondock Saints): All Saints Day.

This character is portrayed by actor David Ferry in both films.

While the [copy of the original script](http://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/boondock-saints-script.html) I found has the fire alarm being pulled, it makes no mention of the character that pulls it. Further research of [All Saints Day](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Boondock-Saints-2-All-Saints-Day.html) (Boondock Saints 2), reveals that this script has an important clue in the opening sequence of the script (on page 7):

> Dolly, dressed as a civilian, pulls the fire alarm.

This sequence recaps the end courtroom scene from the first movie.

Comment: This is why I use a copy editor for any important work. I spell like Andrew "It is a damn poor mind indeed which can't think of at least two ways to spell any word" Jackson. Thanks for the edit.